# How to return error with Express to front-end within a Promise?

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, express

I tried using a `catch` within the promise on client but it doesn't seem to pick up the error.

server:

```
pdf.create(pdfTemplate(transcriptAsObject), {}).toFile(`routes/api/${finalPdfName}`, (err) => {
  if(err) {
    res.send(Promise.reject());
  }

  res.send(Promise.resolve());
 });
```

client:

```
axios.post('/create-pdf', this.state)
  .catch(err => console.log('error hit: ', err))
  .then(() => axios.get('fetch-pdf', { responseType: 'blob' }))
  .then((res) => {
    const pdfBlob = new Blob([res.data], { type: 'application/pdf' });
    saveAs(pdfBlob, 'newPdf.pdf');
  })
  .then(() => console.log('success brotha'))
```

Comment: I think you can trigger the .catch of axios if your backend sends a status code out of the 2XX range. What does `res.send(Promise.reject());` produce when you call your API? Just make sure it sends an error status code like 500

Answer (score 2):

You don't send promises to your client. So both your `res.send(Promise.resolve())` and your `res.send(Promise.resolve())` are not correct.  Instead, you send a response with an appropriate status.

For example, for an error, you would do something like this:

```
res.sendStatus(500);
```

or

```
res.status(500).send("You got an error creating the PDF");
```

The client then interprets that status and decides what to do.  If you get an unexpected error on your server, you would typically set a 5xx status in the response you send back and the client code can then see that error status and react accordingly.

It is up to the client library that you're using for sending an Ajax call whether it makes a rejection out of a 5xx status or not.  The `fetch()` interface built into the browser only makes a rejection out of true network error (no response coming back).  Any response back from the server is considered a successful request from the point of view of `fetch()`.  You will have to look and see how axios handles non-2xx response statuses, whether it makes it into a rejected promise for you or whether you have to explicitly check for the status in the `.then()` handler.

Looking at the [axios documentation](https://www.npmjs.com/package/axios#request-config), it shows this default behavior:

```
validateStatus: function (status) {
  return status >= 200 && status < 300; // default
},
```

which means that it will reject unless the status is 2xx.  So, returning a 500 status from the server will cause an axios rejection in the client request.  This behavior in axios is customizable if you wanted to modify it.

So, in your client-side code, add a `.catch()` like this:

```
axios.post('/create-pdf', this.state)
  .catch(err => console.log('error hit: ', err))
  .then(() => axios.get('fetch-pdf', { responseType: 'blob' }))
  .then((res) => {
    const pdfBlob = new Blob([res.data], { type: 'application/pdf' });
    saveAs(pdfBlob, 'newPdf.pdf');
  })
  .then(() => console.log('success brotha'))
  .catch(err => {
      console.log(err);
  });
```

And, you will then see an error if you return a 500 status (or any non-2xx status) from the server upon an error.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you should put .catch() after .then()

```
axios.post('/create-pdf', this.state)
  .then(() => axios.get('fetch-pdf', { responseType: 'blob' }))
  .then((res) => {
  const pdfBlob = new Blob([res.data], { type: 'application/pdf' });
  saveAs(pdfBlob, 'newPdf.pdf');
 })
 .then(() => console.log('success brotha'))
 .catch(err => console.log('error hit: ', err))
```

And it could be better if you specify an error instead of a promise in your backend API such as

```
  pdf.create(pdfTemplate(transcriptAsObject), 
     {}).toFile(`routes/api/${finalPdfName}`, (err) => {
    if(err) {

     return res.status(500).send(err)

  }

   res.send(Promise.resolve());
  });
```